# pushing items to array in typescript in a structured way

Tags: typescript2.0

I have these items here that I want to push to an array in a set format.
I have declared my array this way

```
finalCount = [];
```

Now I want this array to have items in this format:
animal: Count
For e.g:
dog: 3
cat: 4
cow: 1

And each item in the array should be accessible by providing a index number as well. for e.g finalCount[0] should pick dog.
I tried to push items this way

```
this.finalCount.push(this.animal, this.count);
```

but each item here doesn't go together.
How do I get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push items in your final count array, you can leverage synthax originally introduced with ES2015, [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Now if you want to define the TypeScript type for objects in the finalCount array. You should create the following interface:

```
interface FinalCountItem {
    [animal: string]: number;
}

finalCount: FinalCountItem[] = [];

this.finalCount.push({[this.animal]: this.count});
```

Comment: Thanks @maxletou, it worked the way i wanted it. Now how do i splice of the first item from a list of 3 items in the array. For e.g: how to take off dog:3 from that array and also how do I go about just picking dog.

Comment: To get only the dog from the array: finalCount.filter(c => c.hasOwnProperty("dog")) // To get everything but the dog: finalCount.filter(c => !c.hasOwnProperty("dog"))

Comment: What I meant was just picking the animal not the count and also regarding the splicing the first item from the finalCount array how do I do that. Right now I have it done this way this.finalCount.splice(0,1), but it doesn't work

Comment: I see you probably want to take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Sure will look into it. Thanks maxletou